# Enforce piece of text to be under the figure

Tags: floats, text

I have a problem, that when I post figure in a specific position, the figure posted in other position, I mean even in another paragraph which contradicts the context of figure. For example, I add the figure 1 in the section 1, but the figure is attached to section 2. 
How can I solve this issue ?

```
\subsection{SENTIWORDNET}
```

we know, a word in any language and especially in English has many different meanings even if it’s appeared in many different contexts as noun, verb, adverb and so on. For example, the word '\textit{DOG}'.

```
\begin{figure}[h]
    %\centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.9]{images/SentiwordNet1.png}
    %\caption{Label Distribution of Trained data}
    \label{SentiwordNet1}
\end{figure}
```

The word DOG can used in many contexts with different meaning as example in figure \ref{SentiwordNet2}.

```
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.7]{images/SentiwordNet2.png}
    \caption{Word meaning in Wordnet}
    \label{SentiwordNet2}
\end{figure}
```

(WORD, MEANING) pair is called a LEMMA, which the basic entity in WORDNET. Here is an example for how LEMMA represented in WORDNET.

```
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.7]{images/LEMA_example.png}
    \caption{LEMA in Word-Net}
    \label{SentiwordNet2}
\end{figure}
```

and the resulted file is like

[image]

Comment: the only reason to use the `figure` enviornment is to mark the content as not part of the document flow so it can be re-inserted as needed to help with page breaking, it should always be referenced indirectly via its caption. If the image is part of the document flow you can include it directly without using `figure`.  Here I think you should allow the figure to move, but put the explanatory text in the figure after the image, so move `\end{figure}` after the relevant paragraph.

Comment: Now it's work, Thank you

Answer (score 1):

the only reason to use the `figure` enviornment is to mark the content as not part of the document flow so it can be re-inserted as needed to help with page breaking, it should always be referenced indirectly via its caption.

If the image is part of the document flow you can include it directly without using `figure`.

Here I think you should allow the figure to move, but put the explanatory text in the figure after the image, so move `\end{figure}` after the relevant paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

You can put text inside the figure environment, but you will lose `\parindent` and `\parskip` and it can still move relative to the surrounding text.

You can put the image into a minipage environment with `\captionof{figure}{...}`.  This will preserve text order and will allow page breaks.

The last example puts the text inside the minipage to make them unbreakable.  Note that `\centering` turns off `\parindent` again.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
\rule{1em}{0.5\textheight}

Before text.

\begin{figure}[h!]% equivalent to [htp]
    The word DOG can used in many contexts with different meaning
    as example in figure \ref{SentiwordNet}.
    \vspace{\intextsep}

    \centering
    \includegraphics{example-image}
    \caption{Word meaning in Wordnet}
    \label{SentiwordNet}
\end{figure}

After text.
\newpage

Before text.

The word DOG can used in many contexts with different meaning
as example in figure \ref{SentiwordNet2}.

\noindent\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics{example-image}
    \captionof{figure}{Word meaning in Wordnet}
    \label{SentiwordNet2}
\end{minipage}

After text.

Before text.

\noindent\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
    \parindent=\bibindent
    The word DOG can used in many contexts with different meaning
    as example in figure \ref{SentiwordNet3}.
    \vspace{\intextsep}

    \centering
    \includegraphics{example-image}
    \captionof{figure}{Word meaning in Wordnet}
    \label{SentiwordNet3}
\end{minipage}

After text.
\end{document}
```